# Getting "onNetworkChanged()" warning every few seconds in an Android application

Tags: android, debugging, jobs

I'm getting this warning every few seconds in LogCat in my Android App:

```
JobService    onNetworkChanged() not implemented in androidx.work.impl.background.systemjob.SystemJobService. Must override in a subclass.
```

**How can I fix this or at least get more information to be able to diagnose this warning?**

*Note: I'm getting this warning even when the app is closed.*

---

If it may help, here is the context:

- API 34 (only).
- Using fully Jetpack Compose.
- Using data store.
- Using a few Workers, including periodic ones.